# ActiveModel::Serializer not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a Client model and a method in my controller that should return the nearest clients. I'm using ActiveModel::Serializers but it's not working.

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :path, :url

  def url
    client_url(object)
  end

  def path
    client_path(object)
 end
end
```

controller:

```
def nearby_from_category
    @closest_clients = Client.from_category(params[:category]).
      activated.locateable.all_with_translation(@lang).
      by_distance(origin: remote_ip).limit(2)

    render json: @closest_clients.to_json(include: {
      translations: {only: [:name, :content]},
      pictures: {only: :image}
    })
end
```

javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $(".nav_category").hover(function () {
    var category_dropdown = $(this).children(".category_dropdown");
    var clients_from_category = category_dropdown.children(".clients_from_category");
    var category_dropdown.toggle(0, "hidden");

    $.get($(this).data("url"), function(response) {
        var client = response[0];
        var client_name = client['translations'][0]['name'];
        var client_picture = client['pictures'][0]['image']['thumb']['url'];
        var html;

        html = "<a href='+ client.url +' class='nearest_client'>";
        html += "<img src='" + client_picture +"'>";
        html += client_name;
        html += "</a>";
        clients_from_category.html(html);
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).children(".category_dropdown").toggle(0, "hidden");
  })
});
```

The html that gets output is this:

```
<a href="undefined" class="nearest_client"><img src="/uploads/picture/image/361/thumbimage.jpb</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ActiveModel::Serializers (AMS) you should simply use:

```
render json: @post
```

The whole point of serializers is to move your json structure out of your controllers. So lets start out by getting rid of the `include` hash in the render call:

```
def nearby_from_category
  @closest_clients = Client.from_category(params[:category]).
    activated.locateable.all_with_translation(@lang).
    by_distance(origin: remote_ip).limit(2)
  render json: @closest_clients
end
```

In most cases AMS can figure out which serializer to use for collections by itself by looking at the contents. You can specify it manually with the `each_serializer` option.

To include the translations and pictures you would redefine your serializer:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :path, :url

  has_many: :translations
  has_many: :pictures

  def url
    client_url(object)
  end

  def path
    client_path(object)
  end
end

class TranslationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :content
end

class PictureSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :image
end
```

One big gotcha is that you may be creating a **N + 1** query issue since the associations will be loaded separately for each client unless joined. This is not an AMS specific issue.

The many resulting SQL queries will slow down your server and can cause it to run out of memory. See [the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for potential solutions.

Comment: Both maxcal and Gavin were right, but I accepted maxcal's answer because he was first. Thanks to both!

Comment: Actually Gavin beat me by 40 seconds :)

Comment: Yeah, but you and I made a deal in the previous question :)
Sorry Gavin!

Comment: @MarkoĆilimković back room dealings for SO accepted answers *runs to moderators* `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 2):

This is not working because your controller isn't actually rendering out using the `ActiveModel::Serializer`. You'd need to write it like this:

```
def nearby_from_category
    @closest_clients = Client.from_category(params[:category]).
      activated.locateable.all_with_translation(@lang).
      by_distance(origin: remote_ip).limit(2)

    render json: @closest_clients
end
```

---

In the event that you want to customize the serializer as indicated by the additional args on your `to_json` call, you'd have to modify the `ClientSerializer` that already exists to:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :path, :url

  has_many :translations
  has_many :pictures

  def url
    client_url(object)
  end

  def path
    client_path(object)
  end
end

class TranslationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :content
end

class PictureSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :image
end
```